# Remove .php extension for a generic site

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

But it only work for the site example.com
How can I edit it to work for any site ?

Comment: What do you mean for any site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it to work for multiple hosts just use the variable `HTTP_HOST` instead of the actual site name.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks but in this case it works only with the "folder" name.

Comment: I'm confused. What is the path of your files? Is it or is not in the folder directory?

Comment: Is there not a way to do that for a generic site and path and folder ?

Comment: You're not really answering my question. Where do the files live on any site? Are they in the document root or a subfolder?

Comment: in the root, sorry :)

Comment: Then it should be as simple as removimg the folder name in the rules as I did in the update. Check and see how the update works.